# Device Firmware Update Never Success: XPS 15 9570 Precision 5530

Tags: updates, firmware

Every one or two weeks, my ubuntu 18.10 will popup a software upgrading window asking  me to update device firmware of my laptop. The firmware is XPS 15 9570 Precision 5503 System Update.  But every time after I clicked the 'update' button, it seems nothing happened, and the next time when the newer version of the firmware  arrive again, i can see my version still stay in the original state.  I believe the updating was not happening every time.  But why? How to make the updating success?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any success on this issue? After I clicked update, the system restarted and failed, every time then on, starting ubuntu fails once and in second attempt it can start ubuntu. This start to cause headache to me....